# Proper Object Reference by ID Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text that I wish to display, or not, based on a test. I have placed the text in a <span /id="..."> block, and have found examples that show referencing the id directly (if...then below) or by using the document.getElementById function (...else below).

Both seem to work in my test case. I gather that using the getElementById function is correct. Is it also correct to reference without calling that function, or is this just a case where it works in this browser now, but may break using a different browser or browser version?

Is there a better method do accomplish this?

```
<span id="myText">Some text to display or hide</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SetVisibility()
{
  if (button.checked)
    {
      myText.style.visibility="visible";
    }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("myText").style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `myText.style.visibility="visible";` with `document.getElementById("myText").style.visibility="visible";`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal you did not read the question...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It is not "wrong" with HTML5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - used the two different approaches on purpose . . . he is asking which is the preferred approach and why.

Comment: @epascarello, thank you for the pointer to the very helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/12415287), it is a bad idea to use inline HTML event attributes.

You can also add an event listener by using `getElementById` then adding `addEventListener()` to your `button` element like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var myText = document.getElementById("myText");
  myText.style.visibility = myText.style.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
})
```

```html
<span id="myText">Some text to display or hide</span>
<button id="myButton">SetVisible</button>
```

It would be best to use `eventListener()` to set up event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the support for this seems pretty widespread -- it started in IE and seems to work across Chrome/Firefox/Safari as of my testing just now. However, using global variables is often considered an anti-pattern outside of exceptional cases where it makes sense -- native web APIs or situations where you *need* to be able to access something globally, for example. Otherwise you run the risk of overwriting or being overwritten by other code trying to compete for those names. In short -- in this case, it is almost always better to use `getElementById`, although it is good to be aware that this feature exists.